# Get Activity's 1 Intent extras from Activity's 2 static fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment, android-bundle

I have the following scenario. I use an Intent to go from `SelectRecipeActivity` to `RecipeStepsActivity`. I use a bundle to pass the recipe ingredients and steps with this intent. `RecipeStepsActivity` hosts a static fragment (`RecipeStepsFragment`) where the recipe's ingredients and steps are being shown. My question is what is the best practice to pass the intent bundle to the `RecipeStepsFragment`?

Right now I use `getActivity().getIntent().getExtras()` in `RecipeStepsFragment`'s `onCreateView()` to get the intent's extras from `SelectRecipeActivity` and it works with no problems.

As it is not a dynamic fragment (I don't use a Fragment constructor or newInstance method, it is declared in xml using the `<fragment>` tag) and a fragment transaction is not taking place, I cannot pass the extras using fragment arguments, which I know is the recommended way. Or can I? Am I missing something? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Gabe Sechan's proposal, I used the following way to pass the bundle to `RecipeStepsFragment` from `RecipeStepsActivity`.

1) I receive the intent extras from `SelectRecipeActivity` to `RecipeStepsActivity`'s `onCreate` method.

2) In `RecipeStepsActivity`'s `onCreate` method I get a reference to `RecipeStepsFragment` by calling `findFragmentById` like this:

```
RecipeStepsFragment stepsFragment = (RecipeStepsFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
.findFragmentById(R.id.master_steps_fragment);
```

3) Then I get the intent extras creating a `Bundle`, which I then pass as `RecipeStepsFragment`'s arguments, like this:

```
Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
//Pass the intent extras to the fragment using a bundle
if (args != null) {
   //show Dessert Name in Toolbar
   mRecipe = args.getParcelable(EXTRAS_RECIPE_ITEM);
   assert mRecipe != null;
   setTitle(mRecipe.getName());

   assert stepsFragment != null;
   stepsFragment.setArguments(args);
}
```

4) Now in `RecipeStepsFragment`'s ->`onActivityCreated`<- method (to be sure that the hosting activity has been created and so we have got the intent extras from the previous activity), I simply get the step's 3 arguments like this:

```
Bundle fragmentArgs = getArguments();
```

which contains the same extras `SelectRecipeActivity` passed to the `RecipeStepsActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm assuming you just mean a fragment defined in xml by "static", not a static variable (which is a really bad thing for a fragment).  In that case-  give the fragment an id, use findFragmentById in the Activity's onCreate, cast it as the correct Fragment type, and call a function on the Fragment to pass it the appropriate data.